# fetch image and css files by curl proxy in php

Tags: php, css, curl, proxy

i am using curl library in order to query a proxy server .
i am receiving only the HTML scource from the requested URL and this code don't retreive the image and CSS files and other web page files. please give me an idea to solve this problem.
my code :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://google.com';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '192.168.1.200:3128');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data=curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo '<br />';
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: curl can't do that, you need to parse the HTML and grab all the items individually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostafa,

Well, to approach this problem, I would first try to understand exactly what your browser is doing when you visit a web page. Here's a very basic outline of what happens when you type "http://www.google.com" into your browser's address bar.

1. You tell the browser to load a URL.
2. The browser then makes a request (very much like making a "cURL request") to the address you provided.
3. The contents of that page (in this case, just plain HTML) are returned to your browser.
4. Your browser then reads the HTML file until it finds a link to an image, JavaScript file, CSS file, etc... it then makes ANOTHER query for each of those external resources.
5. While these requests are happening, your browser is continuing to read the HTML file so that it can render the content of the page.
6. Once all of the external things are downloaded and the HTML file is fully rendered, you'll see a complete web page drawn on your screen by the browser.

So, now that we have that out of the way, to fully load a page and all of its resources through a proxy is a lot more complicated then just downloading the HTML file.

To fully load the page, you'll have to not only parse the HTML to **retrieve all of those external files** and store them on your server (temporarily), but also rewrite the original HTML file to link to the external files (CSS, JS, images) that you saved to your server. This way, your browser only has to make requests to the server that is running the cURL script.

**Personal recommendation:** don't re-invent the wheel. Try some existing script to help you out. [PHP Web Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/)

Comment: please tell me how to use PHP WEB PROXY, i haven't found any user manual or sample code .

Answer (score 3):

cURL is text-only.  Typically, it will download the source of the URL, nothing more.

You would need to parse the source using a regex or similar tools to find the images and other resources as they are shown in the source text.

Comment: Parsing HTML with a regex makes kittens steal candy from babies. It's recommended to use an HTML parser instead, like DOMDocument.

Comment: @onteria Those damn kittens.  I'm not a cURL guru, so I just suggested the "simplest" method that I knew, not necessarily the best.  In addition, just between you and I, if someone doesn't know that cURL doesn't download images and CSS files, do you think they're going to be using DOMDocument? ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can replace the src, href statement like this

```
   $result = str_replace('src="','src="'.$url.'/',$data);
   $result = str_replace('href="','href="'.$url.'/',$result);
```

just before print the result

I hope this fix your problem

Comment: So, for example if the image file stand on another server?

Comment: another problem in this solution  : you must have direct access to internet to load image and css files.

Comment: Mostafa take a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295125/how-to-display-images-when-using-curl)